# File modification time before the write started

Tags: filesystems, time

It seems that `stat` command displays the modification time before I started to actually write to the file.

It can be replicated with this script

```
date --iso-8601=ns
touch file.txt
stat file.txt
```

The stat time is few ns before.
The issue usually pops up after some hits.

I see this issue in the following infrastructure
  - ubuntu 16 in the hyperv running on windows
  - ubuntu 18 running in azure or amazon cloud
  - centos running in docker
  - mac

The issue doesn't pop up on my main windows pc.

I got a message that it doesn't pop up if you boot linux on pc.

Comment: By default, the *file system* establishes the file-modification time (not the writing host system).  If there's a time-mismatch between the machines, you'll see this.  By the way, this is probably a duplicate, since it's documented in many places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392975/timestamp-accuracy-on-ext4-sub-millsecond

Synopsis: the filesystem applies timestamps using a cached time, while `date` uses that cached time plus CPU cycles to provide a more accurate (and more recent) time.